# where I can get my flutter App url for my amazon affiliate program?

Tags: flutter, affiliate

i want to add affiliate link in my flutter app..but to get the link i have to enter this
[image]

How i get Mobile App urls because . I have not published my app yet on playstore.
Does anyone have any idea...?

Comment: It is not a mandatory field. Skip that field

Comment: @TamilSelvanC..how i get associate link if i don't mention my App. Please Clarify...